# Is it possible to convert any empty Json object into null?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm working with an API that can return empty Json as a possible value.

the empty Json "{}" can also show up in nested field, for example, if `foo` have a field name `field3` of an object type, it can also be {} if that object type's field are all null values.

My question, how can I convert any "{}" json value into null, so that I can model my class as nullable?

Example API response:

```
{
 "foo" : {}
}
```

or

```
{
 "foo" : {
  "field1" : 123,
  "field2" : "somestring"
  "field3" : {}
 }
}
```

Example Class that I want to deserialize into

```
public class Foo 
{
  public int? Field1 { get; set; }
  public string? Field2 { get; set; }
  public Bar? Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use records and a [custom Deserializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var json = "{\"foo1\" : {}, \"foo2\" : {}}";
var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooContainer>(json);
Console.WriteLine(foo);

record Foo(int? i){
    public static readonly Foo ALL_NULL_FOO = new Foo(i: null);
};
record FooContainer
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullableFooConverter))]
    public Foo? foo1 {get;set;}
    // no attribute on this guy
    public Foo? foo2 {get;set;}
}

class NullableFooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override Foo? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var desFoo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(ref reader, options);
        return (desFoo == Foo.ALL_NULL_FOO) ? null : desFoo;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options: options));
    
}
```

This is the output:

`FooContainer { foo1 = , foo2 = Foo { i =  } }`

meaning foo1 is null, and foo2 is a foo with property i set to null

Records are suited for this because they rapresent an entity and are equal not by reference, as classes are, but if all properties are equal.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO the  fastest, the simpliest and the easiest way is

```
json = json.Replace("{}","null");
```

or you can create an extension

```
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json.ReplaceEmptyByNull());

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ReplaceEmptyByNull(this string json)
    {
        return json.Replace("{}","null");
    }
}
```

Comment: But only if you are certain that your json can't contain `"{}"`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Pls read the question " ANY empty Json "

Comment: Your answer will replace any `{}` that appears inside a string constant. Meaning that it is not safe unless you know that no strings will contain this sequence of characters. An example of a "clbuttic" mistake.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman if you want to be very happy and sleep sound  you can use ":  {}",  but I think that OP is a different kind of person and sleeps well in any case

Comment: Your code would replace `"field2" : "somestring {}"` with `"field2" : "somestring null"`. But you don't seem to understand that.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman  Pls, give me a break, I am not creating a json library to replace something with something, we have quite simple objects and this solution only for this case.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my own global JsonConverter to iterate over the JObject and any nested JObject or JArray children. Which work in my case since the API response is always a JObject or type of class.

```
public class EmptyJsonToNullConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType.IsClass);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        EnumerateJObject(token);

        return token.ToObject(objectType);
    }

    private void EnumerateJObject(JToken token)
    {
        foreach (JProperty prop in token)
        {
            string name = prop.Name;
            JToken value = prop.Value;

            if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                EnumerateJArray(value);
            else if (value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                if (value.IsNullOrEmpty())
                    token[name] = null;
                else
                    EnumerateJObject(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void EnumerateJArray(JToken token)
    {
        var jArray = (JArray)token;
        if (jArray.Count == 0)
            return;

        foreach (var item in jArray.Children())
            EnumerateJObject(item);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the serialization converter.");
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token)
    {
        return (token == null) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    }
}
```